# Does how I got my understanding of an article need to be cited?

Tags: citations

Forgive me if this is a stupid question, but I just want to make sure that I’m taking the appropriate steps; I’m a student in University, and I write a lot of essays/reviews throughout the year. I like taking breaks and reading fictional stories to relax, but of course my brain sort of travels a lot to various different places, which includes school related tasks. I wanted to take a break from trying to understand one particular article that I was reviewing, and I only fully realized how the article’s thesis related to its conclusion while I was in the middle of reading one story (I had stopped to process it and I was about to go back into it again). However, it wouldn’t make sense to reference the story in my review, since I didn’t take any information from it, correct?

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/142182/will-taking-a-vacation-hurt-your-academic-career-recommendation-letter/142208#142208

Answer (score 4):

Definitely **no.** I think you know this, but for the benefit of future readers of this post: The purpose of a citation is not to provide a diary of the author's thought process, but rather to acknowledge the prior work done before yours and trace the *logic and evidence* from which your work follows. It helps no one to know what story you were reading, or whether you had a particularly nice breakfast that stimulated your thoughts. Save it for your blog or your memoirs.

Comment: Yes, personal heuristics are seldom useful.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! I really appreciate it, and I apologize for taking this long to answer!

Answer (score 0):

> I only fully realized how the article’s thesis related to its conclusion while I was in the middle of reading one story...However, it wouldn’t make sense to reference the story in my
> review, since I didn’t take any information from it, correct?

You needn't cite the story, but you could mention it in the acknowledgements, especially if the story hinted at the relation (in some way). Such acknowledgements should probably be included sparingly. For instance, acknowledging your soap manufacturer, because the idea came to you in the shower, doesn't seem particularly noteworthy.* Whilst acknowledging an author for opening a new perspective seems more noteworthy. Ask yourself whether your readers will be intrigued.

*Unless, perhaps, you had just changed soaps and the change in viscosity inspired you to adapt your experiment (in a similar fashion) leading to success.

Comment: Oh, good idea. Never seen that in Acknowledgements.

Comment: I’m sorry it took so long to reply, but thank you for answering my question, I really appreciate it!